# Java annotation validation

Tags: java, validation, annotations

How to validate a property that should be grater than zero?and not zero.I used built in annotation `@Min(0)` but how can i ignore the zero?Is there any other built in annotation for this case?

```
@Min(0)
default public Double getAmd1() {
    return (Double) get("amd1");
}
```

Comment: Going by the explanation in the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html), why not just use `@Min(1)` ?

Comment: property is a double. so it can be 0.5 for example.@KrishnanMahadevan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [@DecimalMin](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/DecimalMin.html) annotation
It provides a boolean parameter `inclusive` which fits your needs.
Sadly `Double` is not supported because of rounding issues, but BigDecimal is. You can then get the value as double by using `getDouble()`.

So you can try something like this:

```
@DecimalMin(value = "0.0" ,inclusive = false)
private BigDecimal amd1;

public BigDecimal getAmd1() {
    Double d = (Double) get("amd1");
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(d);
}
```